# Undefined <fieldname> error for ActionItem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am getting following error:

> undefined method `comments=' for
>
> ## <ActionItem:0x0000010643cb80>

Code below:

**correspondence_controller.rb**

```
class CorrespondenceController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery
  def add
    correspondence = ActionItem.new
    correspondence.event_id = params[:event_id]
    correspondence.comments = 'cccc' #gives error
    correspondence.user_id = params[:user_id] ##gives error

    if correspondence.save
      render :json => { :status => :ok}
    else
      render :json => { :status => :fail}
    end
  end
end
```

**correspondence.rb**

```
class Correspondence < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

**Migration file**

```
class CreateCorespondences < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :correspondences do |t|
      t.integer :event_id
      t.integer :user_id
      t.text :comments

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `correspondence = ActionItem.new` to `correspondence = Correspondence.new`.